# How to use webpack combine angular2 with existing spring boot server

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, angular, spring-cloud

I  want the existing spring boot gateway  as the backend server, instead of the angular 2 .

> that is i want the angular2 combines to the spring gateway .

Assume :

> the angular 2 webpack-dev-server on port 8090 , and there is a
>   page index.html
>
> spring boot gateway on port 8080: and all the api .

I want to open

```
localhost:8080
```

to see the angular2 index.html ,

how to implement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an example of an implementation ，

front is :  https://github.com/springboot-angular2-tutorial/angular2-app

and  spring-server is : https://github.com/springboot-angular2-tutorial/boot-app ,

Reference to this example , I have successfully build a simplify
 demo .

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up proxy for your backend. I know that webpack-dev-server based on Express. So, I can give you a clue how to run it with Express:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.use('/api', function(req, res) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/api' + req.url;
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

/* serves all the static files */
app.get(/^(.+)$/, function(req, res){
    res.sendFile( __dirname + req.params[0]);
});

app.listen(8090);
```

Then you refer to backend API by /api/entry-point .

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpProductDiscountService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    getProductDiscounts() {
        return this._http.get('api/1.0/product-discount')
            .map(res => res.json())
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks your clue , I have found another  implements  method . Because i use spring .